# Why does template copy constructor override default copy constructor?

Tags: c++, templates

**Edit** Updated Code:

```
class Any
{
public:
    Any()
    {
    }

    Any(const Any &other)
    {

    }

    Any(Any &other) // added per Ben's answer
    {
    }

    Any(Any &&other)
    {
    }

    Any(const char *value)
    {
    }

    template<typename T>
    Any(const T &value)
    {
    }

    template<typename T>
    Any(T &&value)
    {
        cout << "move ctor" << endl;
    }

    template<typename T>
    Any(const vector<T> &value)
    {
    }

    template<typename T>
    Any(vector<T> &&value)
    {
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<string> numbers;
    numbers.push_back("one");
    numbers.push_back("two");
    numbers.push_back("three");
    numbers.push_back("four");

    Any anyNumbers(numbers);
    Any anyNumbersCopy = anyNumbers;

    return 0;
}
```

prints:

> "move ctor"

Why is this happening?

Is there any way to force the default copy constructor to be called instead of the templated const& constructor?

I would like to avoid making the template constructor explicit if possible so that I can still implicitly construct the class like this;

```
Any number = 5;
```

Comment: Provide a SSCCE that exhibits the problem.  Overloading prefers non-templates to templates.

Comment: And, there is no such thing as a "template copy constructor".  Your template function defines a family of converting constructors, including a conversion from `const Any&`, but not a copy constructor.

Comment: You'll need a constructor for `Any&`, not `Any&&`, to help in your example.  The template provides `Any&` due to reference-collapsing rules, and is **not** only used for moving.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps your real code looks more like this?

```
class Any
{
public:
    Any(){}

    Any(const Any &other)
    {
    }

    template<typename T>
    Any(T &&other)
    {
    }
};
```

In this case, the template is a better match for `Any& other` (not `const`!).  The solution then is to provide a non-const non-template copy constructor overload:

```
class Any
{
public:
    Any(){}

    Any(const Any &other)
    {
    }

    Any(Any &other)
    {
    }

    template<typename T>
    Any(T &&other)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: This was it. Using the non const copy constructor does result in the correct behaviour. Now I am getting a compiler warning though: warning C4521: 'Any' : multiple copy constructors specified

Comment: Section 12.8p4 of the Standard specifically allows having multiple forms of the copy constructor in a single class... I'd recommend disabling that warning.